# Download a file from a linux remote server using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have backup all my website files to a zip folder from cpanel. Now I want to download this zip folder to my local drive. I searched on internet and found command line code `scp` but its not working for me.

```
scp myusername@remotehost.edu:file.zip D:/
```

I am currently in `public_html` directory using SSH.

Comment: Looks like you're on a Windows host, why not just use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)?

Comment: scp command as such won't work on Windows. You can use WinSCP for GUI interface, or if you prefer command line utility, go for pscp which is very similar in usage to scp.

Answer (score 3):

Check this tutorial, it's very well explained

[scp command line to securely copy files over ssh, between Linux, Mac or Windows](http://www.garron.me/linux/scp-linux-mac-command-windows-copy-files-over-ssh.html)

**Examples:**

> scp *.txt user@remote.server.com:/home/user/ That is going to copy all
>   files with .txt extension to the folder /home/user in the
>   remote.server.com host
>
> scp -r miguel@10.1.2.2:/home/user/ user@10.1.2.3:/home/user/

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are using windows, so you should have a look at winscp (http://winscp.net/), which is a graphical interface for scp.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a command-line from windows then you could give [pscp](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html) a try from the [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a SFTP client such as

- [Flash FXP](http://www.flashfxp.com/) - a paid ftp client with great options
- [Filezilla Client](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) a free and opensource client